# testing an iphone app on multiple devices

Tags: iphone, ios, testing

i have developed an iphone app.
i have no problem testing it on my device.

now i would like to have it on a few more devices, for the QA team and for presentation.

The app is not yet in appstore and we are not yet moving to the enterprise developer program.

how can we do that?

Comment: Check the almighty inter web for "adhoc distribution iOS".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you can test on your own device, this means you're already enrolled in the personal iOS development program. That means, you can add up to 100 UDIDs of iOS devices in your account and distribute ad-hoc builds for these devices.

Just create a distribution certificate, add UDIDs of test devices, create distribution profile, sign your build with it and send to your testers. They will be able to install it via iTunes.

Here's a [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/145-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html) to the Apple docs with some more specific info about it.

Comment: That link is broken.  Maybe it was moved here?  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use Test Flight for this purpose. You can install your app on multiple devices and you can track the crashes and logs through check points.

https://testflightapp.com

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://testflightapp.com/. You can build the app and deploy it to many devices through that effortlessly.

It works really well, all users have to do to get it on their device is click a link in an email they get sent from the device they want it on and it installs the app automatically.

Answer (score 0):

We have a couple of devices at our startup company, and also have very old iPods. Perhaps you can get some for very little second hand? What I do is keep one of each model of iPhone and iPod touch and install the latest version of the OS that runs on it. So I have iPhone 2G and iPod touch 1G with OS 3.1.3; iPhone 3GS, iPhone 4, and iPod touch 2G with OS 4.0; and a WiFi iPad with OS 3.2. Only one of the phones has cell phone service.

As for my builds, I build with SDK 4.0 and set OS 3.1.3 as the earliest target. If you claim to support a certain OS, you must have tested on the device with that OS.

Off Topic: I think supporting versions old of an OS when a free update is available shouldn't be done for too long. People need a bit of "help" updating.

Comment: correct, i think too that the support should not be too long.
in my case however we have the same devices, it was just a matter of deplyoing on them